# How can I set default value in parameter substitution as an array of elements?

Tags: zsh, array

I'm using zsh, and I have this function:

```
function timer-raw() {
    # Just think `loop fsayd` is `echo hi` for the purposes of this question.
    eval "sleep $((($1)*60))" && eval ${(q+@)@[2,-1]:-loop fsayd}
}
```

`timer-raw`'s first argument tells it how many minutes to wait; The rest of the arguments, if present, would be `eval`ed as if typed on the command line, after the wait:

```
timer 3 echo sth
# After 3 minutes, echoes `sth`.
```

However, if no further arguments are supplied, I want it to run the default command `loop fsayd`:

```
timer 4
# runs `loop fsayd` after 4 minutes
```

The problem is that I want `loop fsayd` to be substituted as two words, but I don't know how. I tried these variations, too, but they didn't work either:

```
"${(q+@)${@[2,-1]:-loop fsayd}}"
"${(q@)${(q@)=@[2,-1]:-loop fsayd}}"
"${(qq@)=@[2,-1]:-loop fsayd}"
```

By "didn't work", I mean either a simple `timer 0` would fail by a `command not found`, or that `timer 0 ff hi 'man hi jk k'` failed to return the correct number of input arguments. (`ff() echo "$#"`)

Note: I do not want to use `test -z "${@[2,-1]}"`.

Comment: Please show how exactly you call your function, what happens and what you want to happen. Maybe you can replace the default value with something like `if [ check_that_your_variables_are_defined ] ; then eval your_variables ; else loop fsayd ; fi`

Comment: @Bodo As the comment says, `loop fsayd` is a very simple command that can be substituted by `echo hi` if you want to test it yourself. The problem is that it needs to be substituted as `"loop" "fsayd"` but it is substituted as `"loop fsayd"` which causes a `command not found` error.

Comment: Repeating the information from the question doesn't help. I suggest to [edit] your question to add more information. You should explain your variable substitution and what would be the case when the script will not use the default value (`echo hi`). For `echo hi` a double `eval eval ${...}` works, but I don't know what would be the other case.

Comment: @bodo Better now?

Comment: there are of course alternatives to using default values to solve this particular case but I guess those are outside the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lol I figured it out:

```bsh
function timer-raw() {
    eval "sleep $((($1)*60))" && eval ${(q+@)@[2,-1]:-${(z)/#/loop fsayd}}
}
```

This substitutes (`${name/pattern/repl}`) the contents of the non-existent variable named "" (nothing) -- which is an empty string -- replacing the beginning of the (empty) string (pattern `#`) with loop fsayd, while doing word splitting (options `(z)`)..... :D

Comment: Feel free to un-upvote the original solution :)

Answer (score 1):

If it is okay to define the defaults in a variable, you should be able to do:

```bsh
function timer-raw() {
    defs=( loop fsayd )
    eval "sleep $((($1)*60))" && eval ${(q+@)@[2,-1]:-$defs}
}
```

Personally I would not use eval and just do:

```bsh
function timer-raw() {
    defs=( loop fsayd )
    sleep ${1}m && ${@[2,-1]:-$defs}
}
```

Comment: It's the best thing if there is no better way. (`eval` is necessary to make it accept aliases.)

Comment: Can't say for sure; didn't figure out a better way yet :)